# Is it possible to convert datatype when alter the table with check constraint in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, check-constraints

Here, I am only going to get CheckListNo (integer) from select statement "Check_No" ( character varying). when am execute this, error showing like this 'operator does not exist: character varying = integer'. So, I want to check without changing datatypes.

For an example,  SELECT  "Check_No"
  FROM "Project_CheckList_Options"  let we see I defined "check_No" column as a integer if I want to get records in character varying. I can use just "check_No":: character varying then I can see column records in character varying type without affecting integer datatype. So like that Is it possible to convert datatype when alter the table with check constraint in postgresql?

```
 alter table "Project_Configuration" 
  add check("CheckListNo" in (SELECT  "Check_No"  FROM "Project_CheckList_Options"))
```

Comment: You can't create a check constraint based on a sub-select. What you are looking for is a foreign key constraint.

Comment: i used before this query ,but it shows same error 
alter table "Project_Configuration"  add constraint operator does not exist: character varying = integer'"Fk_ProjTimesheetData_Projworkallocation" foreign key("CheckListNo" )
 references "Project_CheckList_Options" ("Check_No") on delete restrict on update cascade

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, **edit** your question. If that fails it means that the columns `"CheckListNo"` and `Check_No"` are defined with different data types (one as integer one as varchar). You can't compare apples and oranges, so there is no way you can create such a constraint. You have to change the data type of one of the columns, so that e.g. both are integers. Please show us the complete `create table` statements for both tables (again: **edit** your question and add the code)